# Positioning with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Hello guys im trying to recreate this: [image]

This is what i have: [image]

I did everything except i cant seem to get the nav potion to the right of the page.Any suggestions what i can do to make it work? What is the best way to do it and why?

index.html :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="./resources/images/img-myt-logo.jpg" alt="Our logo">
        <span>My Times</span>
      </div>
        <nav>
          <span>World</span>
          <span>U.S</span>
          <span>Tech</span>
          <span>Science</span>
        </nav>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

style.css :

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.logo{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

nav span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 40px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.logo span {
  color: MediumAquamarine;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: google 'flexbox please'. i usually use staic width on the left side stuff and `flex 1 1 auto` on the right side child box. It should vertical center the text by default.

Answer (score 2):

add `justify-content: space-between;` to header

```css
    header {
      display: flex;
      font-family: Verdana;
           justify-content: space-between;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: bold;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }

    .logo{
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      margin-left: 20px;
    }

    nav span {
      display: inline-block;
      padding-right: 40px;
      justify-content: flex-end;
    }
    .logo span {
      color: MediumAquamarine;
      padding-left: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="./resources/images/img-myt-logo.jpg" alt="Our logo">
    <span>My Times</span>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <span>World</span>
    <span>U.S</span>
    <span>Tech</span>
    <span>Science</span>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Did that work for you? don't forget to accept the answer please. Thanks
(https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

@itsolidude

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, you need to justify the content so that it opens up space between your logo div and the nav element. Easiest way to do this is add justify-content to your CSS for the header...

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

.logo{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

nav span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 40px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.logo span {
  color: MediumAquamarine;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

The justify-content you have on nav span would justify the content within the nav, not justify the nav element itself within the header.